# Page not found (404) - The current path, editEstHab/, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem when I want to update an existing object... in another project, I used a similar lines of code, but now, it doesn't work when I'm going to save the actual information...

the more stranger thing is... at the end says **The current path, editEstHab/, didn't match any of these.**, but when I search on my project, the only time that I use **editEstHab/** is in urls.py...
So... help :( I don't have any clue about what is my mistake.

**models.py**

```py
class habitacion(models.Model):
    nroHabitacion = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    tipoHabitacion = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
    tipoCama = models.ForeignKey(tipoCama, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False)
    accesorios = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
    precio = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    estado_habitacion = models.ForeignKey(estadoHab, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipoHabitacion
```

**forms.py**

```py
class UpdateHabForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = habitacion
         fields = ['estado_habitacion']
```

**views.py**

```py
def editHab(request,id_habitacion):
    # llamando datos de habitacion seleccionada
    hab = habitacion.objects.get(id=id_habitacion)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UpdateHabForm(instance=hab) 
    else:
        form = UpdateHabForm(request.POST, instance=hab)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'hab' : hab
    }
    return render(request,"editEstHab.html",context)
```

**urls.py**

```py
    path('editEstHab/<id_habitacion>', views.editHab, name="editEstHab"),
```

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqZ5I.png)

Comment: You have to include `id_habitacion` also when you make requests. ie, you need to try **`http://localhost:8000/editEstHab/2345`** where `2345` is the `id_habitacion`

Comment: Where do I have to include id_habitacion exactly? D: in views.py? because when I click on "edit", it takes the ID (as you can see in urls.py) and shows me the second window seen in the photo, but at the moment I click on "Save", the third window appears

Comment: You have written your code to accept the id_habitacion. The next thing you need to do is, pass the id_habitacion from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is the url of the POST request

If you leave the `action` attribute of the html form blank, it should work fine

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
  {{field}}
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit" name="button">UPDATE</button>

</form>
```